# W3C Web Authentication (WebAuthn) Cannot login, credential setup required

Tags: keycloak, w3c, jboss-tools, webauthn

I am getting the following error when setting up **W3C Web Authentication (WebAuthn)**.

```
We are sorry...

Cannot login, credential setup required.
```

[image]

I have existing user accounts on the platform and upgraded the server from `v7.0.0` to `v8.0.0`. I get the error when logging in and choose `WebAuthn` from the credential list.

[image]

Here is the error that the server logs.

```
00:26:41,982 WARN [org.keycloak.services] (default task-47) KC-SERVICES0013: Failed authentication: org.keycloak.authentication.AuthenticationFlowException: authenticator: webauthn-authenticator
```

Here are screenshots of my configuration.

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Here is the full stack trace of the error

```
at org.keycloak.keycloak-services@8.0.0//org.keycloak.authentication.DefaultAuthenticationFlow.processSingleFlowExecutionModel(DefaultAuthenticationFlow.java:448)

at org.keycloak.keycloak-services@8.0.0//org.keycloak.authentication.DefaultAuthenticationFlow.processAction(DefaultAuthenticationFlow.java:151)

at org.keycloak.keycloak-services@8.0.0//org.keycloak.authentication.AuthenticationProcessor.authenticationAction(AuthenticationProcessor.java:958)

at org.keycloak.keycloak-services@8.0.0//org.keycloak.services.resources.LoginActionsService.processFlow(LoginActionsService.java:294)

at org.keycloak.keycloak-services@8.0.0//org.keycloak.services.resources.LoginActionsService.processAuthentication(LoginActionsService.java:265)

at org.keycloak.keycloak-services@8.0.0//org.keycloak.services.resources.LoginActionsService.authenticate(LoginActionsService.java:261)

at org.keycloak.keycloak-services@8.0.0//org.keycloak.services.resources.LoginActionsService.authenticateForm(LoginActionsService.java:322)

at jdk.internal.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor834.invoke(Unknown Source)

at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)

at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)

at org.jboss.resteasy.resteasy-jaxrs@3.9.0.Final//org.jboss.resteasy.core.MethodInjectorImpl.invoke(MethodInjectorImpl.java:138)

at org.jboss.resteasy.resteasy-jaxrs@3.9.0.Final//org.jboss.resteasy.core.ResourceMethodInvoker.internalInvokeOnTarget(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:517)

at org.jboss.resteasy.resteasy-jaxrs@3.9.0.Final//org.jboss.resteasy.core.ResourceMethodInvoker.invokeOnTargetAfterFilter(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:406)

at org.jboss.resteasy.resteasy-jaxrs@3.9.0.Final//org.jboss.resteasy.core.ResourceMethodInvoker.lambda$invokeOnTarget$0(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:370)

at org.jboss.resteasy.resteasy-jaxrs@3.9.0.Final//org.jboss.resteasy.core.interception.PreMatchContainerRequestContext.filter(PreMatchContainerRequestContext.java:356)

at org.jboss.resteasy.resteasy-jaxrs@3.9.0.Final//org.jboss.resteasy.core.ResourceMethodInvoker.invokeOnTarget(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:372)

at org.jboss.resteasy.resteasy-jaxrs@3.9.0.Final//org.jboss.resteasy.core.ResourceMethodInvoker.invoke(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:344)

at org.jboss.resteasy.resteasy-jaxrs@3.9.0.Final//org.jboss.resteasy.core.ResourceLocatorInvoker.invokeOnTargetObject(ResourceLocatorInvoker.java:137)

at org.jboss.resteasy.resteasy-jaxrs@3.9.0.Final//org.jboss.resteasy.core.ResourceLocatorInvoker.invoke(ResourceLocatorInvoker.java:100)

at org.jboss.resteasy.resteasy-jaxrs@3.9.0.Final//org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher.invoke(SynchronousDispatcher.java:440)

at org.jboss.resteasy.resteasy-jaxrs@3.9.0.Final//org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher.lambda$invoke$4(SynchronousDispatcher.java:229)

at org.jboss.resteasy.resteasy-jaxrs@3.9.0.Final//org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher.lambda$preprocess$0(SynchronousDispatcher.java:135)

at org.jboss.resteasy.resteasy-jaxrs@3.9.0.Final//org.jboss.resteasy.core.interception.PreMatchContainerRequestContext.filter(PreMatchContainerRequestContext.java:356)

at org.jboss.resteasy.resteasy-jaxrs@3.9.0.Final//org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher.preprocess(SynchronousDispatcher.java:138)

at org.jboss.resteasy.resteasy-jaxrs@3.9.0.Final//org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher.invoke(SynchronousDispatcher.java:215)

at org.jboss.resteasy.resteasy-jaxrs@3.9.0.Final//org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.ServletContainerDispatcher.service(ServletContainerDispatcher.java:227)

at org.jboss.resteasy.resteasy-jaxrs@3.9.0.Final//org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.HttpServletDispatcher.service(HttpServletDispatcher.java:56)

at org.jboss.resteasy.resteasy-jaxrs@3.9.0.Final//org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.HttpServletDispatcher.service(HttpServletDispatcher.java:51)

at javax.servlet.api@2.0.0.Final//javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:590)

at io.undertow.servlet@2.0.26.Final//io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletHandler.handleRequest(ServletHandler.java:74)

at io.undertow.servlet@2.0.26.Final//io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterHandler.java:129)

at org.keycloak.keycloak-services@8.0.0//org.keycloak.services.filters.KeycloakSessionServletFilter.doFilter(KeycloakSessionServletFilter.java:91)

at io.undertow.servlet@2.0.26.Final//io.undertow.servlet.core.ManagedFilter.doFilter(ManagedFilter.java:61)

at io.undertow.servlet@2.0.26.Final//io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterHandler.java:131)

at io.undertow.servlet@2.0.26.Final//io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler.handleRequest(FilterHandler.java:84)

at io.undertow.servlet@2.0.26.Final//io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletSecurityRoleHandler.handleRequest(ServletSecurityRoleHandler.java:62)

at io.undertow.servlet@2.0.26.Final//io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletChain$1.handleRequest(ServletChain.java:68)

at io.undertow.servlet@2.0.26.Final//io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletDispatchingHandler.handleRequest(ServletDispatchingHandler.java:36)

at org.wildfly.extension.undertow@18.0.0.Final//org.wildfly.extension.undertow.security.SecurityContextAssociationHandler.handleRequest(SecurityContextAssociationHandler.java:78)

at io.undertow.core@2.0.26.Final//io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)

at io.undertow.servlet@2.0.26.Final//io.undertow.servlet.handlers.RedirectDirHandler.handleRequest(RedirectDirHandler.java:68)

at io.undertow.servlet@2.0.26.Final//io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.SSLInformationAssociationHandler.handleRequest(SSLInformationAssociationHandler.java:132)

at io.undertow.servlet@2.0.26.Final//io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletAuthenticationCallHandler.handleRequest(ServletAuthenticationCallHandler.java:57)

at io.undertow.core@2.0.26.Final//io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)

at io.undertow.core@2.0.26.Final//io.undertow.security.handlers.AbstractConfidentialityHandler.handleRequest(AbstractConfidentialityHandler.java:46)

at io.undertow.servlet@2.0.26.Final//io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletConfidentialityConstraintHandler.handleRequest(ServletConfidentialityConstraintHandler.java:64)

at io.undertow.core@2.0.26.Final//io.undertow.security.handlers.AuthenticationMechanismsHandler.handleRequest(AuthenticationMechanismsHandler.java:60)

at io.undertow.servlet@2.0.26.Final//io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.CachedAuthenticatedSessionHandler.handleRequest(CachedAuthenticatedSessionHandler.java:77)

at io.undertow.core@2.0.26.Final//io.undertow.security.handlers.NotificationReceiverHandler.handleRequest(NotificationReceiverHandler.java:50)

at io.undertow.core@2.0.26.Final//io.undertow.security.handlers.AbstractSecurityContextAssociationHandler.handleRequest(AbstractSecurityContextAssociationHandler.java:43)

at io.undertow.core@2.0.26.Final//io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)

at org.wildfly.extension.undertow@18.0.0.Final//org.wildfly.extension.undertow.security.jacc.JACCContextIdHandler.handleRequest(JACCContextIdHandler.java:61)

at io.undertow.core@2.0.26.Final//io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)

at org.wildfly.extension.undertow@18.0.0.Final//org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.GlobalRequestControllerHandler.handleRequest(GlobalRequestControllerHandler.java:68)

at io.undertow.core@2.0.26.Final//io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)

at io.undertow.servlet@2.0.26.Final//io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.handleFirstRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:269)

at io.undertow.servlet@2.0.26.Final//io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.access$100(ServletInitialHandler.java:78)

at io.undertow.servlet@2.0.26.Final//io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler$2.call(ServletInitialHandler.java:133)

at io.undertow.servlet@2.0.26.Final//io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler$2.call(ServletInitialHandler.java:130)

at io.undertow.servlet@2.0.26.Final//io.undertow.servlet.core.ServletRequestContextThreadSetupAction$1.call(ServletRequestContextThreadSetupAction.java:48)

at io.undertow.servlet@2.0.26.Final//io.undertow.servlet.core.ContextClassLoaderSetupAction$1.call(ContextClassLoaderSetupAction.java:43)

at org.wildfly.extension.undertow@18.0.0.Final//org.wildfly.extension.undertow.security.SecurityContextThreadSetupAction.lambda$create$0(SecurityContextThreadSetupAction.java:105)

at org.wildfly.extension.undertow@18.0.0.Final//org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentInfoService$UndertowThreadSetupAction.lambda$create$0(UndertowDeploymentInfoService.java:1504)

at org.wildfly.extension.undertow@18.0.0.Final//org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentInfoService$UndertowThreadSetupAction.lambda$create$0(UndertowDeploymentInfoService.java:1504)

at org.wildfly.extension.undertow@18.0.0.Final//org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentInfoService$UndertowThreadSetupAction.lambda$create$0(UndertowDeploymentInfoService.java:1504)

at org.wildfly.extension.undertow@18.0.0.Final//org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentInfoService$UndertowThreadSetupAction.lambda$create$0(UndertowDeploymentInfoService.java:1504)

at io.undertow.servlet@2.0.26.Final//io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.dispatchRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:249)

at io.undertow.servlet@2.0.26.Final//io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.access$000(ServletInitialHandler.java:78)

at io.undertow.servlet@2.0.26.Final//io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler$1.handleRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:99)

at io.undertow.core@2.0.26.Final//io.undertow.server.Connectors.executeRootHandler(Connectors.java:376)

at io.undertow.core@2.0.26.Final//io.undertow.server.HttpServerExchange$1.run(HttpServerExchange.java:830)

at org.jboss.threads@2.3.3.Final//org.jboss.threads.ContextClassLoaderSavingRunnable.run(ContextClassLoaderSavingRunnable.java:35)

at org.jboss.threads@2.3.3.Final//org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor.safeRun(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1982)

at org.jboss.threads@2.3.3.Final//org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor$ThreadBody.doRunTask(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1486)

at org.jboss.threads@2.3.3.Final//org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor$ThreadBody.run(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1377)

at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)
```

Comment: I'm also facing the same issue, did you got the solution?

Comment: Clay Risser and @SakthiPanneerselvam: I am apparently facing the same problem now. Did you manage to solve it at the time. If so, could you please share the solution? Thanks.

Comment: Sorry I haven't tried in a while. A lot of changes have been made since then so hopefully it works now.

Answer (score 1):

This is a very late response but I hope it will help others.

In your "Browser 2FA Forms" Under "Auth Type", tick REQUIRED. This works for my case.